# RabbitMQ JAVA Spring Configurations - spring.rabbitmq.ssl.key-store

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ssl, rabbitmq

I am trying to connect my Spring application to a RabbitMQ server.
I have in my src/main/resources folder an application.properties file containing the following properties:

```
spring.rabbitmq.port=port
spring.rabbitmq.username=user
spring.rabbitmq.password=pass
spring.rabbitmq.host=hostname
spring.rabbitmq.ssl.verify-hostname=true
spring.rabbitmq.virtual-host=virtualHost
spring.rabbitmq.ssl.enabled=true
spring.rabbitmq.ssl.algorithm=TLSv1.2
spring.rabbitmq.ssl.key-store=client-file
spring.rabbitmq.ssl.key-store-password=client
```

The "client-file" is also in the same directory - src/main/resources. However, when I build the application - I recieve the following error:

```
Factory method 'rabbitConnectionFactory' threw exception; 
nested exception is org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
class path resource [client-file] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

My file is not being recognized... I might need to have some full path, but am not sure what it should look like. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hello @Uri Shapira, could you ever solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
...
spring.rabbitmq.ssl.key-store=classpath:/client-file
spring.rabbitmq.ssl.key-store-password=client
```

I did put mine in the resource folder '..\src\main\resources'.

Comment: seems like classpath or file reference is all that works. if you are reading from local filesystem, then use use `file:` instead. see here for more [info](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/resources.html#resources-resourceloader)

Answer (score 0):

use file:file_path if you are placing the file on a directory location(or a mounted drive) outside your app.